# What does this option "Scheme/Edit Scheme/Options/Allow Location Simulation" means in XCode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-location

I didn't get any proper apple docs on this setting.
We recently got screwed up because of this as whenever app launches or "Try to get user location" this alerts will comes up.

"Location Manager Error : Operation could not be completed(KCLErrorDomain error 0)"

Resulting in very bad user experience.
So anybody can throw some light on this issue?

Comment: Have you checked your Location Manager and looked around?

Comment: Yeah.What's your point?

Comment: Well it says Location Manager Error so the error must be related to your Location Manager. Have you investigated code that deals with the Location Manager or could you post your Location Manager code up so we can help you thats my point.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because you have the Scheme/Edit Scheme/Options/Allow Location Simulation checked. But you have not specified the default location set properly.